# Allow Null if Right Join Select doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, right-join

I am working with a data set where I needed to pull it certain values from the same column of data, but place them into two different columns

Example

```
> OrderID   ProductID   PRODNAME     NORECIP  PPRECIP   ITEMTTL    MD        SRE    POST  
  14764     2306        DW14RE_FC    187      $1.85     $345.95    10/29/20  NULL   FC 
  14935     2341        DW14RE_STD   205      $1.00     $205.00    11/5/20   No     STD
  14977     2343        DW14RE_UP_FC 439      $1.00     $439.00    11/5/20   No     NULL  
  15072     2341        DW14RE_STD   3220     $1.00     $3,220.00. 11/11/20  No     STD
```

The SRE Column and POST columns both have a RIGHT JOIN as shown below

```
RIGHT JOIN [uStore].[dbo].[OrderProductDialValue] AS OPDV1 ON
 OPDV1.[OrderProductID] =
 [uStore].[dbo].[OrderProduct].[OrderProductID] AND OPDV1.[DIALID] IN
 ('14479',  '14480',  '14481',  '14482',  '14483',  '14950',  '14972', 
 '14993',  '15022',  '15030',  '15039',  '15055',  '15089',  '15096', 
 '15155',  '15163',  '15192',  '15217',  '15241',  '15261',  '15279', 
 '15298',  '15317',  '15334',  '15349',  '15365',  '15381',  '15402', 
 '15425',  '15449',  '15473',  '15497')   

RIGHT JOIN [uStore].[dbo].[OrderProductDialValue] AS OPDV ON
OPDV.[OrderProductID] = [uStore].[dbo].[OrderProduct].[OrderProductID]
AND OPDV.DIALID IN ('14885',  '14949',  '14971',  '14998',  '15021', 
'15029',  '15088',  '15095',  '15132',  '15162',  '15191',  '15216', 
'15240',  '15260',  '15278',  '15297',  '15316',  '15333',  '15424', 
'15448',  '15472',  '15496')
```

With the above in place, I drop my NULL values from the last two columns

```
> OrderID   ProductID   PRODNAME     NORECIP  PPRECIP   ITEMTTL    MD        SRE    POST  
  14935     2341        DW14RE_STD   205      $1.00     $205.00    11/5/20   No     STD
  15072     2341        DW14RE_STD   3220     $1.00     $3,220.00. 11/11/20  No     STD
```

Is there any way have my selection of only those criteria listed in my `RIGHT JOIN` but allow for `NULL` values if it doesn't match those criteria to ensure I get my full data set?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`????

Comment: Change `RIGHT JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. I don't understand why you did `RIGHT JOIN` in the first place, unless you simply don't understand what it means, so I'd highly recommend you find yourself a SQL guide and study up on how OUTER JOINs work.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "The SRE Column and POST columns both have a RIGHT JOIN as shown below".  I just don't follow what this means.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: @DaleK and Andreas, thank you for your help in suggesting that I use LEFT JOIN. I would say that I am a weekend warrior when it comes to SQL. I took a course many years back and just don't use it enough to retain everything that I should. 

Andreas - I find more often then not, the purposes of people posting a questions for help is the following:
1. They are so deep in their code that they can't see the real problem even if they knew the answer.
2. They partially know the way, but need that additional help.